# How to always start from the root Activity if Application is recreated?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three Activities in my Application say A,B and C, Where A is the Login Activity and starts B after login and B later starts Activity C. Now if I am on B or C and the Application goes in background and later Android decides to kill my Application (for what so ever reason). I want to always start from A. However if the Application was not killed I would like to start from the Activity where I left (B or C). How to achieve that ?

I have tried using clearTaskOnLaunch as suggested by so many answers but either that doesn't suit my requirements or I am not using that properly.

Comment: Maybe write something in onStop()...(I'm actually not sure)?

Comment: that should have been what you said.

Comment: How we will know whether or not Android will kill our App @Keyser from background ?

Comment: We can't store any variable because whole Application is closed and recreated next time...

Comment: Why dont you just start the an intent to launch the main class in every activities `onPause()` ?

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen I don't think OP wants to handle pausing. _"However if the Application was not killed I would like to start from the Activity where I left"_

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used to always start from the 1st Activity

Put this code in your B or C

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),A.class);//this will close all activities except A
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.putExtra("exit", true);
            startActivity(i);
```

and in A's OnCreate

```
if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("exit", false))
     finish(); //This will finish your main activity
```

Comment: And where in the Activities do you put that code? (That's the most relevant part)

Comment: You can put it under any button like EXIT

Comment: I'm not the OP, and I know you can put it anywhere, but this doesn't really answer the OP's question...